# Event listener when Safari extension's popover closes

Tags: safari-extension

Is there a way to detect when the Safari extension's popover closes. Something like a event that is fired when the popover closes? 
I do not see any event listener listed on the API doc but is there a workaround for it ? It would be helpful to perform clean up actions once the popover closes.

Answer (score 4):

You can cleanup before next popover open:

```js
safari.application.addEventListener('popover', function(event) {
    event.target.contentWindow.location.reload();
}, true);
```

Comment: True, but not a good idea! If you reload at popover open, user will see the page loading, which makes for a bad UX.
It is better to listen for `blur` on `window` inside popover and do the cleanup with a slight delay (like 500ms).
Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860101/can-you-detect-when-a-safari-popover-closes?answertab=active#tab-top