# Can you detect when a Safari popover closes?

Tags: popover, safari-extension

We're trying to have multiple popovers in our extension and we need to know when the popover closes so we can change the popover value on the button.

Is there any listener for that?

Comment: IIRC, a `blur` event is triggered on the window object when the popover closes.

Comment: That's the answer. Why don't you move your response to an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the popover is closed, the `window` object receives a `blur` event.

So, something like this in the popover will work:

```
window.onblur = function () {
    // do stuff when popover is closed
};
```