# Is there any Safari Popover hide event in Safari extension?

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

I am developing a safari extension. I am creating dynamically popover on popover event from extension. I want to remove the created popover as soon as the extension popover is not being displayed. 
Is there any event like popoverHideEvent or something?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can listen for the `blur` event on the popover's `window`.

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860101/can-you-detect-when-a-safari-popover-closes)

Comment: That's correct. But the problem is: just after creating a popover, popover's contentWindow is empty. So 'blur' event does not get attached to the popover's contentWindow.